# Finding a single function $y=f(x)$ (with the minimum possible parameters) satisfying $7$ properties

Tags: calculus, curves, regression, mathematical-modeling, least-squares

For one experiment with four different samples, the data points of each sample showing a different shape of the curve:

---

Sample #1:

- $y$ increases as $x$ increases.
- the curve has no inflection points.
- it has an upper bound but has no lower bound.

---

Sample #2:

- $y$ increases as $x$ increases.
- the curve has one inflection point.
- it has an upper bound as well as a lower bound.
- $\frac{dy}{dx}$ increases before the inflection point, then decreases after the inflection point (with the same rate).

---

Sample #3:

- $y$ increases as $x$ increases.
- the curve has one inflection point.
- it has an upper bound as well as a lower bound.
- $\frac{dy}{dx}$ increases before the inflection point slowly, then will decrease after the inflection point fast.

---

Sample #4:

- $y$ increases as $x$ increases.
- the curve has one inflection point.
- it has an upper bound as well as a lower bound.
- $\frac{dy}{dx}$ increases before the inflection point fast, then will decrease after the inflection point slowly.

---

So for illustration, I made artificial data points (plot only, but no values):

---

Sample #1:

[image]

---

Sample #2:

[image]

---

Sample #3:

[image]

---

Sample #4:

[image]

---

Now the required is to find a general form of $y=f(x)$ that has a minimum possible number of model parameters, with the properties:

$\text{(P1)}$ $y$ increases as $x$ increases. (This property is common for all four samples illustrated above).

$\text{(P2)}$ $y$ has an upper bound. (This property is common for all four samples illustrated above).

$\text{(P3)}$ Depending upon the value of the model parameters, fitted curve should be fixed *automatically* to have either $0$ or $1$ inflection point. (Sample #2, Sample #3, and Sample #4 have $1$ inflection point, but Sample #1 has no inflection points). So the model should work in any case.

$\text{(P4)}$ Depending upon the value of the model parameters, fitted curve should be fixed *automatically* to have or not to have a lower bound.

$\text{(P5)}$ $y=f(x)$ is continuous in the interval $[x_\text{min},x_\text{max}]$.

$\text{(P6)}$ $y=f(x)$ is differentiable in the interval $(x_\text{min},x_\text{max})$.

$\text{(P7)}$ $y=f(x)$ is integrable (using only elementary functions) in the interval $(x_\text{min},x_\text{max})$.

---

**My Attempt ( with failure ) :**

A possible model for Sample #1 is

$$y=a-be^{cx},$$

and a possible model for Sample #2 is

$$y=\frac{1}{a-be^{cx}},$$

So I was thinking that a possible model that can be used for any case is to add these together, so we have the model:

$$y=C_1+C_2e^{C_3 x}+\frac{1}{C_4+C_5 e^{C_6 x}}$$

but I failed because this model may have discontinuities because the denominator can be zero, so I resolved this by squaring $C_4$ and $C_5$ so the denominator will never be zero. However, there is still a problem about Sample #3 and Sample #4. Sample #3 grows slowly then it reaches the equilibrium faster, and the opposite for Sample #4 which grows fast then it reaches the equilibrium slowly.

---

***EDIT:***

I found a function that fixes itself according to the data points:

$$y=C_1+C_2 e^{C_3e^{C_4x}}$$

This curve is good because it fits any of the four behaviors illustrated above.

However, this does not satisfy property $(\text{P7})$, so I included this as a part of my attempt, also a good reason to include this attempt is to demonstrate how to required function need to be flexible so it can fit my data.

---

Your help would be appreciated. THANKS!

Comment: One way to solve this problem would be to use a parameter space with only four elements, each corresponding to a function satisfying the properties of your samples 1-4.  This would be the smallest possible number of model parameters (only one parameter, with 4 values). But I suspect that this is answer is not satisfying for you (is it?). Do you want that the function is continuous/differentiable in the model parameters?

Comment: Why not restrict $C_4,C_5$ to positive numbers instead of squaring them (which still doesn’t avoid division by zero unless you restrict them anyway)?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I mentioned: "However, there is still a problem about Sample #3 and Sample #4. Sample #3 grows slowly then it reaches the equilibrium faster, and the opposite for Sample #4 which grows fast then it reaches the equilibrium slowly." That bad guess does not work even though $C_4$ and $C_5$ are positive.